# How to get perforce to pull only files that don't exist in workspace

Tags: perforce

How do you do some sort of download/resume with perforce?

I have a perforce repository with a large code base. While syncing there was a network error that caused the p4 client to break.

I want to start pulling only the files that don't already exist in work space> How do I accomplish that?

I have tried:

`p4 sync -f //depot/BRANCH/...` (copies all over from start)

`p4 sync //depot/BRANCH/...` (Says all files are synced), but I can see some files are missing in the workspace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
p4 diff -sd //Depot/BRANCH/... | p4 -x – sync -f
```

This will do what you need.

p4 diff -sd:

Show only the names of unopened files that are missing from the client workspace, but present in the depot.

Pipe that output to the force sync, to only force sync the missing files.

Comment: "p4 diff -sd //Depot/BRANCH/... > updateList.txt", then "p4 -x updateList.txt sync -f" also works. You can see the updated files in updateList.txt